# Android устанавливается неактуальная версия приложения

Tags: android, google-play

Я тестирую в  своем приложении вход в Google account и Leaderboard. Для этого выпускаю альфа версии.

С первыми версиями все ок. Потом свежие выпуски перестали поступать в Google Play.

Удаляю приложение со смартфона. Устанавливаю по ссылке полученной в Console. И все равно получаю старую версию.

В чем причина отсутствия новых версий?

Comment: попробуйте в настройках очистить кэш приложения Google Play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашелся в загадочной кнопке "Дезактивировать версию".

Кажется есть некое число "Активных" версий. То есть, выпуская очередную альфа версию, я должен был дезактивировать предыдущие. Иначе все они были активны.

Кнопка находится управлении версией которую хотите отключить. В блоке управление тестировщиками.